# react native redux with flatlist for some infinite scrolling on local

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

my api does not offer me pages to fetch with pages. In this case i am using redux as well and currently i am splitting my result into 10 rows and using flatlist to display only the 10 results.

what i am planning to do with redux is that, at the end of onEndReached to call the action function to pass LOAD_MORE to reducer and merge with another 10 more records on my current state and pass back to my component again.

but i am not sure how should i do on the onEndReached

here is what i have for my component

```
 render() {
       if (this.props.loading) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.activityIndicatorContainer}>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={true}/>
            </View>
            );
    } else {
        return (

          <Container style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Content>
          <FlatList
          ref='listRef'
          data={this.props.currData}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.sno+item.name+item.cid}
          onEndReached={this.handleMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0}
          />
          </Content>
          </Container>

          );
    }
}
handleMore = () => {
    this.props.loadMore();
};
// The function takes data from the app current state,
// and insert/links it into the props of our component.
// This function makes Redux know that this component needs to be passed a piece of the state
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        loading: state.dataReducer.loading,
        data: state.dataReducer.data,
        currData: state.dataReducer.currViewData
    }
}

// Doing this merges our actions into the component’s props,
// while wrapping them in dispatch() so that they immediately dispatch an Action.
// Just by doing this, we will have access to the actions defined in out actions file (action/home.js)
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
}
```

action

```
export function loadMore(){
    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log("load more");
        //dispatch({type: LOAD_MORE, data: test});
    };
}
```

this is a simple testing to see if i can hit load more in console log when i scroll to the bottom. It seems like i am not able to hit it. Possible how can i setup something like this?

my result return has alot of data and i prefer to load 10 at once and scroll down for another 10, my only problem is my api does not have pages to support the usual infinite scroll

Comment: I believe you are missing `extraData={this.props}` in your `FlatList`. As stated in readt docs... "A marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it implements PureComponent). If any of your renderItem, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the data prop, stick it here and treat it immutably."

Comment: added that into my flatlist, my function is still not able to load when i am at the bottom of the screen scroll. Not able to fire or trigger the onEndReached it seems and setting the threshold more than 0 will cause it to auto load when my page is ready instead of scrolling it to bottom for load

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: Does in redux have infinite scroll in Flatlist. If it have Flatlist infinite scroll anyone give any reference for this